# Converting Edge/IE JavaScript WheelEvent deltas to native scroll amounts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, mousewheel

In Edge and Internet Explorer, I'm noticing a strange issue with wheel events not equating to their expected scroll amounts. Even though the [`deltaMode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaMode) values are reported as `DOM_DELTA_PIXEL` (`0`), the number of pixels found in `deltaY` is greater then the number of pixels actually being scrolled in a small scrollable div.

Take this code for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
        #scroller {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="scroller">
            <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
            <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
            <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
        </div>
        <script>
(function() {'use strict';
    var scroller = document.getElementById('scroller');
    scroller.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
        var scrollY = e.deltaY;
        console.log('scrollY:', scrollY);
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('scroller.scrollTop:', scroller.scrollTop);
        }, 250);
    });
})();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the console I'm seeing values like this:

```
scrollY: 101.8499984741211
scroller.scrollTop: 28
```

In other browsers like Chrome, these values match or are at-least very close.

So the amount actually being scrolled is not the same as what is reported. Why is this, and can we get the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the values are different is because IE and Edge actually scale the DOM pixels down based on how much of the window the scrolling area being scrolled takes up.

This complicates computing the proper scaling for a browser, and since IE/Edge are the only ones doing it, you will have to use some form of user-agent sniffing.

To get the correct amount of scrolling, you need to multiply the `deltaY` by `(scroller.clientHeight / window.innerHeight)` (and likewise with `deltaX`).

Here is that same sample with these adjustments:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
        #scroller {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="scroller">
            <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
            <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
            <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
        </div>
        <script>
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var scroller = document.getElementById('scroller');
    scroller.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
        var deltaY = e.deltaY;
        var scaleY = scroller.clientHeight / window.innerHeight;
        var scrollY = deltaY * scaleY;
        console.log('scrollY:', scrollY);
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('scroller.scrollTop:', scroller.scrollTop);
        }, 250);
    });
})();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which gives the following output in my console:

```
scrollY: 28.199999577518067
scroller.scrollTop: 28
```

Note that `scrollTop` values do not have floating points, so if you want the values to match exactly, you can `Math.round` them.